# error while invoking an online header file involving futures

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have written a template function **wait_for_all**(vector) which blocks until every future in the vector is ready and then exits.

The problem and an implementation were originally given by Stroustrup in "The C++ Programming Language", 4th ed, pg 1243. However, I have changed the implementation, since Stroustrup's didn't handle exceptions thrown by a passed future. I have successfully tested my implementation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43bc327ac9f77f48. This solution combines the function and the tester in a single source file.

However, when I split the function and the tester into 2 separate files on coliru, I run into an error for the tester.
Header: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f3e11b783baf2e7  : It's OK
Tester: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9badf42d85fc4e96  : Gives an error

The compilation output for the tester is:

```
ln -s /Archive2/5f/3e11b783baf2e7/main.cpp wait_for_all.h    #link to the header file 

clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors main.cpp -o wait_for_all_test

./wait_for_all_test

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-28d9f5.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_setspecific@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

bash: line 11: ./wait_for_all_test: No such file or directory
```

What exactly is this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to link against the `pthread` library.  Add `-lpthread` to the `clang++` invocation.

Comment: @G.M., it worked [perfectly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4960a21fc81ec352).